# Minimum distance for accelerating electrons through an electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

For ease of framing this question, lets say we have electron gun such as those found in a CRT. An electron that travels from the cathode end to the accelerating anode will gain energy in eV equivalent to the potential difference in volts between those two electron gun elements. My question is, is there a minimum distance (even if microscopic) that's required for this to be true? In other words, is there acceleration "slip" whereby the energy gained in eV by the electron is smaller than the potential difference between cathode and anode due to insufficient distance between the two?

Comment: No, there is no minimum distance barring QED and quantum gravity limits due to too large fields across too short distances. However, before reaching those limits, the much more likely issue you would have to face, first, is that the definition and precision of the voltages will be insufficient to determine what you want. All the quantum materials you want to play with have finite minimum spreads, and the potential difference will also vary smoothly, even if we try very much to have almost discontinuous changes. I think you should worry about other things instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!